# set document root for external calls

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot, local-area-network

I'm using mod_userdir to set my document root to

```
/home/user/server/public_html/
```

I also setup a virtual host that will redirect for the ServerName `domain.com` to

```
/home/user/server/public_html/domain.com/
```

In that vhost config I also set the document root to that same directory.
Adding a line `127.0.0.1 domain.com` to my hosts file this all works like a charm.

My problem is that if I call that url from my local network externally via

```
192.168.0.1/~user/domain.com/
```

the document root is set to `/var/www` instead of `/home/user/server/public_html/domain.com/`

Is there a way to set the document root to the correct path in such case?

Comment: I found out that the `/var/www` comes from the default vhost configuration. There I can hard-code the appropriate DocumentRoot. But it seems it is not possible to set it according to the directory that has been called or pass the Directory as an argument.